# iMac 2010 i7 blowing fuses

Tags: imac, fuse

My iMac keeps blowing the fuse in the power lead plug while it is asleep! I have replaced the lead, still blows fuse, I have tried another power outlet and I plugged the lead into a plug board guarded by a 5amp fuse, the fuse in the plug blew, not the fuse in the plug board, so it would appear that current is coming out of the machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a short in the PSU, or the cable is faulty. Do you have another power cable you could try?

Comment: You should allways try to provide the complete information regarding your problem. In hardware issues, those details tend to be the version and revision of the hardware pieces (is iMac 2010 enough or does it have a more techy name? I think they do), sometimes even the serial number (in this case I think that the charger serial number would be enough, in case someone can do something malicious with your mac's SID, which I dont really know!). The main reason behind this is that it may be a known issue with manufacturation and people will help you faster.

Comment: In this particular case, I'd advise you to connect it in a SAI and see if it blows the SAI's fuse aswell, then you'll know it's not something related to your house, but to your laptop (or go to a friend's house and do the same experiments you do at home). Looks stupid, but electricity is tricky sometimes ;). Anyway, if it was your house it will most likely affect other devices aswell.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a hardware failure. Take it to a repair shop.